# Can I remove the heat sink and put it back without removing and reapply the thermal paste?

Tags: cpu, thermal-paste

I built my computer yesterday and when I started it it ran for a second then it shut down and it won't start again. I've checked everything else and now I want to check if the heat sink has enough contact with the processor. Do I need to remove the thermal paste I applied yesterday or can I reuse what's on. Potentially add more if required?
Thanks

Comment: Can you? Sure; Should you replace it, Absolutely

Answer (score 3):

Properly applied thermal paste is a thin (not thick) layer of paste between the mating parts. In this case between fan and CPU.

When you remove the fan, you will likely (90%) disturb the evenness of the layer of thermal compound.

So you should definitely clean the parts (isopropyl alcohol) and re-apply new paste.

You should always do this.

Answer (score 0):

If the thermal compound was applied yesterday, you really dont need clean the old off or to apply more.  Maybe just add a small dab if you see some blank spots, which means you didnt add enough.  It will respread between the surfaces.